# HTTP request equivalent of lb web-client import --full

Tags: logicblox

How can I achieve the same functionality as `lb web-client import --import file.csv --full http://service-uri` with an HTTP request made with a tool like cURL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update data, you can use:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/csv" --data-binary @file.csv http://service-uri
```

or if you want to replace data, you can use:

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type: text/csv" --data-binary @file.csv http://service-uri
```

Comment: Thanks @rob-vermaas. I have noticed that this doesn't work for entities with constraints, like `Entity(x) -> Entity:size[x] = _.` In this case, attempting to replace data (via `lb web-client import` or curl) results in a functional dependency violation.